# Edit a not geometric table via a flow WFS

Tags: qgis, wfs, table, relates

I want to know if it is possible to modify a non-geometric table via a flow WFS in QGIS.

I have a flow WFS in QGIS with a layer connected to a table on which we can add several recordings (relation 1-n).

I have no problem adding an object on the first one but it is impossible to add recording over the second, the edition is not allowed.